# Responsive data tables - alternatives for axis and scope attributes

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

[This page](http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/) has a solution for responsive data tables that I really like.  It basically turns each row into its own table (almost like a list of 'info cards').  My issue with it is that you have to generate CSS with duplicate data.  I'd prefer to write styles that would allow the content of the ::before pseudo-element simply reference the appropriate th element.

Such a thing seems to me to be on the edge of what the CSS spec was really designed for, but I'd like to give it a shot.

A comment on the previously mentioned article referenced an 'axis' attribute.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td tells me that axis and scope are both obsoleted and may be unsupported.

Is there an easy (CSS-only) way without doing any extra work on either the server or with js client-side to get the content of the before to be the text in the td's corresponding th?

Comment: I seem to remember someone mentioning the possibility of putting JavaScript code in the content attribute of a pseudo-element.  I haven't been able to track it down, and have never used it myself.  I'm wondering if you could do DOM traversal in such a script to nab the th content using CSS* this way.  (*not actually 'pure' css, and maybe not advisable :)  It looked something like el:before {content: url(javascript:;alert('do stuff here'));}  I've only seen it mentioned once ever.

Comment: Ah - found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23144736/browser-support-and-scope-of-execution-for-javascript-in-url-directive-for-css-a  Based on my one simple test it may not be an option, since it didn't initially appear to work in the current Chrome release.