# Browser support and scope of execution for JavaScript in url directive for CSS attributes -

Tags: javascript, css

This page https://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part1#Cascading_stylesheets mentions that the url directive for attributes that support it can contain javascript.

First, since this seems like a potential security issue I would like to know if any browsers discontinued support for it.

Second, assuming there's widespread support for it and I wanted to use it to do something useful, like DOM traversal relative to a `::before` pseudo-element, what scope does the script execute in?  If I use the `this` keyword does it reference the element that the `before` is tied to?

As a note, I tried this out in Chrome 34 and couldn't get it to run the script.  I had:

```
<style>
  h1:before {
    content: url("alert('hi')");
  }
</style>
```

Loading it with an h1 on the page didn't show an alert, and inspecting the style in the developer tools it had the yellow triangle alerting me to the value being invalid.

Comment: Would the url not need to be `javascript:alert('hi')`?